# Auto populating Excel Table from keywords, error checking for defined names, etc

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to find a solution with either excel or visual basics.

I have an expanding column of remarks on multiple sheets that I need to search through for a keyword (I’m using the word “change” or “chang” to capture “changing” when needed)
When this keyword is found, I need it to give back the cell address, along with a defined name I’ve set up (one for each sheet).

I was able to make a table on a “summary sheet” to include the “new comment”, address, and defined name, and it works well enough. My only concern now is if I add a new row and therefore add a new comment in the column on one sheet, I will have to go back and add a row to my table, and make sure the address and defined name are also corresponding to that “new comment”. This will get very messy and errors can occur, especially since I could have 20+ sheets.

So far all I have been using is excel formulas. But I have also been playing around with excel macros to try and accomplish this (with no luck).

Any help would be greatly appreciated! And I of course can explain this better if need be.

Edit: I added a picture of the general basis of what I’m trying to accomplish. I can’t add the code I’ve been trying as it’s on my work laptop- so I made a simple mock-up of my sheet to include here. I took pictures of the highlighted cell in sheet 1 to show the formulas, and then a picture of sheet 2.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVxBU.jpg)

Comment: If you include the code you tried, we will be able to provide better and more accurate advice. As general advice, you'll want to use [Range.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) with `LookAt:=xlPart`. The `Find` method returns a [Range Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)), so you can get that found range's address, sheet name, or any other related data. There are plenty of examples and tutorials for Range.Find on this website and others.

Comment: Hi there- since the work is on my work computer and I can’t share it, I made a simple mock-up and added a picture of it. Either excel formulas or vba would be helpful for me to try. I just want to go about this the best way possible. Thanks!